# Does shell script invoked by java get killed when the java process is killed?

Tags: java, shell, processbuilder

I have a few doubts on process termination. My use case is such that

1. Java process invokes a shell script process through Process Builder
2. The shell script invokes a new process x

Does process.destroy() in java also kill the process x along with shell script?

What happens when the Java process is killed while x is running? Is both shell script process and process x killed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no tie between a child process and its parent.

Both process can know each other ids, but there is not a hard link between them.

Generally what happens to children of a process when it is killed is platform dependent, so there is not guarantee that when you kill a process created from java also the children of that process will be killed too. Additionally you program can have different behaviour on different operating systems.

Comment: So, there could be a possibility of only the Java process gets killed, but the script doesn't in few cases (based on operating system)... Is that so?

Comment: Yes, it depends on how the operating system handle a kill of a process.

Comment: Then how could we kill the process (like shell script) invoked from other process like Java..

Comment: Consider the case where a shell script (script.sh) is invoked from a Java process (say abc.java). What happens when a process invoked from this shell script hangs due to some error (like infinite looping) ? In such cases how could I kill the process from Java ?